# How send invititaion facebook for all friend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now I use method for invite user with `fb_frnd_id`:

```
function send_invitation(fb_frnd_id){
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'IdiotMinds Programming Blog...',
            to:fb_frnd_id
        });
    }
```

How to send invite for all ID's, when `fb_frnd_id` is array of ID's

Edited:
When I click button "Invite Friend" I get via Ajax the window with the next HTML/JS code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=518575261542061"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function send_invitation(fb_frnd_id){
        fb_frnd_id.map(function(a,b) {
            FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
                message: 'Message...',
                to: a
            });
        });
    }
    function fb_logout(){
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            parent.location ='<?=base_url(); ?>';
        });

    }
</script>
<ul  class="fb_frnds">
    <?php
    foreach($friends['data'] as $val){
        ?>
        <li ><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $val['id']; ?>/picture" width="30" height="30"/>
            <div  class="frnd_list"><?php echo $val['name']; ?><input type="checkbox" name="user[]" value="<?=$val['id']?>"></div>
        </li>

    <?php  }  ?>
</ul>
```

After I select friend and push button "Invite". So nothing happens, what is problem?

Comment: If I will select 20 friends, for each need to confirmation?

Comment: Can you describe what your "Invite" Button does?

Comment: When I click "Invite" the scripts gives all selected checkbox and after calls method `send_invitation`

Comment: Maybe FB Api does not support to call `FB.ui` at lot of times.
Are not there any error message(s) in the console?

Comment: No there are not messages in console

Comment: Did it work before? I mean with 1 invite?

Comment: Yes, I tried invite one person, is not too. I have got example from here:http://demos.idiotminds.com/fbinvites/

Comment: Do you have your code uploaded somewhere? If yes can you show me please?

Comment: I see then I push button "invite" is run request to FB, but not response

Comment: The script is called nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so nice, to send to all users but the solution can be the following:

```
function send_invitation(fb_frnd_id){
     fb_frnd_id.map(function(a,b) {
        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'IdiotMinds Programming Blog...',
            to: a
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, as you wrote, "array of ids"

Comment: Yes it is on that format. var fb_frnd_id = [1,2,3];
I dont know how do you store it, but with my solution should been passed as.

Comment: Thanks you, can you see my question again, Have updated yet :)